# Can Windows VS Code run git commands via ssh on Ubuntu host connected to git repository

Tags: git, ubuntu, ssh

I don't know if this is possible, but I figured I'd ask.
I like developing on my Windows laptop, but to connect to our Git repository, we have to install all the tools on an Ubuntu host.  In addition, the code I'm writing is for Linux, so I ultimately need to push it to the host for testing and then commit it via ssh at the command-line.

Is there any way such that VS Code can run the appropriate commands from my Windows laptop on the Ubuntu workstation to commit the code?

Comment: Why do you need to install tools on a Ubuntu host? You can connect directly to a Git repository from Windows.

Comment: Unfortunately our company doesn't make all the git and custom source control tools available for Windows, so that's why I have to run it on my Linux box :(

Answer (score 1):

You can clone, modify and commit locally with your VSCode, then push through ssh to the remote repo on Linux.
It needs to [be a bare repo](http://www.saintsjd.com/2011/01/what-is-a-bare-git-repository/).

```
git remote -v
auser@aLinuxMachine/a/path/to/remote/repo.git
```

You can then checkout the files of that bare repo to your actual folder on Linux.
Create a post-receive hook file (make it executable).

```
cat /a/path/to/remote/repo.git/hooks/post-receive

#!/bin/sh
unset GIT_INDEX_FILE
export GIT_WORK_TREE=/path/to/actual/files
export GIT_DIR=/a/path/to/remote/repo.git
git checkout -f
```

Once pushed you can run/test your code on Linux. Any Git operation can still be done locally on Windows.

Comment: What I was hoping to figure out is how to run the commands on the Linux host,  not my local machine.  Otherwise I have to commit on my laptop, push to Linux host, and then run all the commit commands yet again.  At that point I might as well just SSH straight to the Linux host and then run the git commands on the Linux host.  I could also use an Ubuntu laptop and avoid all of this, but I was hoping I could pull this off with my Windows laptop.  It does look like VS code has some plugins that allow you to connect to a workspace over ssh, so that might be the best bet.